# How to create a custom selectionmode in winforms listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox in a winforms application that I would like to give a selection behavior that is different than the built in options for the control.If I choose multi-extended, I get what we are accustomed to - ability to use shift or control to select multiple items in the list. The multi-simple option lets you select individually and leave the item selected until you delect it. I'm trying to deal with a slightly different problem that could be solved by a combination of the two options. My users want to be able to use the shift key to highligh a long list and they don't want to accidentally lose their selection if they mistakenly click on one other item in the list. My thought was to keep everything hightlighted until they click a clear button. I kind of think they are asking for something that is not what Windows is meant to do and should not be allowed to do but I thought would post the question so see if anyone has done this before.

Comment: Hmm, there is something wrong with that ListBox.  Probably stuffed to gills with entirely too much info.  Fix that first.  Only then consider to store the selections, with an Undo button do fix mistakes.

Comment: It's a box of thousands of values - not my design - hahaha - said all programmers. I'm going to spend some more time thinking about this.

Comment: Then try using a CheckedListBox instead, where the user "checks" the items they want to process.

Comment: LarsTech - perfect - that's what I've changed it to. For the next version, I'll have more input into design. Thanks.